# Unity light scripting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started Unity last week, but I have a few years of programming experience. I want a light to come on when the game ends. Here is my code, the light doesn't light up.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Collide : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

    light.intensity = 1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your code tells me something completely different from your description. You want a light to come on when the game ends? Then why use an OnTriggerEnter?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle any bool by setting it to the opposite of its current value:

```
myBool = !myBool;
```

So you can toggle a light source by toggling its enabled state:

```
myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
```

Now you want to do that if you press a certain button:

```
Light myLight = lightPoint.GetComponent("Light");

if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
}
```

If you copy/paste the code as is, it won't work. The code given is in C#, so you'd need to create a C# script (with all the attendant file/class name matching) and put the if expression inside the Update function.

Comment: is this helpful ? hope  u got that answer?